# eventlistener is not firing upon click/submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

My event listener isn't firing. I put a breakpoint inside the line `testRun.addEventListener` but it never reaches the breakpoint. So I think this means that the function never executes. I can't seem to figure out why.

my html:

```
  <form>
    <input id="hdfs-test" type="radio" name="test-select" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HDFS
    <input id="hive-test" type="radio" name="test-select" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HIVE
    <input id="hdfs-hive-test" type="radio" name="test-select" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">BOTH

    <textarea id="event-textarea" rows="8" class="form-control" placeholder="Events..."></textarea>

    <input id="submit-test" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Data to describe what kind of test
    var testData = {
        "timestamp": "",
        "hive": 0,
        "hdfs": 0,
        // Contains a list of testData objects
        "beacons":[]
    };

    var selectedTest = document.querySelector('input[name=test-select]:checked');
    var testRun = document.getElementById("submit-test");
    testRun.addEventListener('submit', function() {
        var testType = selectedTest.id;
        if (testType == "hdfs-test") {
            testData["hdfs"] = 1;
            testData["hive"] = 0;
        } else if (testType == "hive-test") {
            testData["hdfs"] = 0;
            testData["hive"] = 1;
        } else if (testType == "hdfs-hive-test") {
            testData["hdfs"] = 1;
            testData["hive"] = 1;
        }
        var events = document.getElementById("event-textarea").value;
        // check in valid input
        var eventSource = events.replace("],[","],,,,[");
        // beaconLists allows users to submit --> [{beacon1}, {beacon2}, ...], [{beacon3}, {beacon4}, ...]
        var beaconLists = eventSource.split(",,,,");
        for (var i = 0; i < beaconLists.length; i++) {
            // inspect one list in beaconLists [{beacon1}, {beacon2}, ...]
            var beaconList = beaconLists[i];
            try {
                // list of JSON objects
                var beaconObjList = JSON.parse(beaconList);
                for (var j = 0; j < beaconObjList.length; j++) {
                    var beaconObj = beaconObjList[j];
                    if (beaconObj["data"] && beaconObj["application"]) {
                    //    successful parse to find events
                    //    describe beacon being tested
                        alert("yes");
                        var beacon = {
                            "app_name": beaconObj["application"]["app_name"],
                            "device": beaconObj["application"]["device"],
                            "device_id": beaconObj["application"]["device_id"],
                            "os": beaconObj["application"]["os"],
                            "os_version": beaconObj["application"]["os_version"],
                            "browser": beaconObj["application"]["browser"],
                            "beacon": beaconObj
                        };
                        // append to testData
                        testData["beacons"].append(beacon);
                        // reset beacon so we can append new beacon later
                        beacon = {};
                    } else {
                    //    notify event isn't in the correct format?
                        alert("no");
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
            //     notify bad JSON
                alert("failed");
            }
        }
        alert("hi");
        console.log(testData);
        //$.ajax({
        //    type: "POST",
        //    url: "/test/",
        //    data: testData,
        //    success: function () {
        //        alert("yay");
        //    },
        //    failure: function () {
        //        alert("boo");
        //    }
        //});

    });

});
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have to attach the event to the form and not the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testRun = document.getElementById("submit-test")` which is the button, not the form. You need to submit the `form` not the `button` itself. Unless you want to just test for the click...

then you need

```
testRun.addEventListener('click', function(){...});
```

Though I would still recommend firing on `submit` just in case the user hits `ENTER` instead of clicking the submit button.

Comment: hmmm so to submit the form, something along the lines of var `i = document.getElementById("form-id"); i.addEventListener("submit",...)`?

Comment: Exactly... and since you are using jQuery I'd just use `i.submit(function(){...});`. Using the `addEventListener` would be more for if your form was added to the DOM after `window.onload` and you want to make sure it still fires. (Folks, correct me if I'm wrong on that explanation.)

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching it to the form, rather than the button.

Comment: what if I had "click" instead of "submit"?

Comment: Use $("#submit-test").click(function(){});